# Compiling libmodplug on windows

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a release version of [love2d](http://love2d.org) on windows. I got all the dependencies downloaded / compiled. However, I have one last problem that I cannot fix:

> The object or library file
>   'lib\libmodplug.lib' was created with
>   an older compiler than other objects;
>   rebuild old objects and libraries

I had similar issues with other dependencies, however I was able to compile those dependencies. The libmodplug source does not provide a Visual Studio solution or project file, and I couldn't find any hints on how to compile this under windows.

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio C++ Express 2010.

Thanks in advance!